Why does Visual Studio Custom DebuggerVisualizer behave erratically in VS 2022 and VS 2022 preview - "Could not load this custom viewer"
Spent a few days trying to get a DebuggerVisualizer running but ran into many difficulties and problems. Finally I isolated the errativ behavior of (my?) Visual Studio installations, 2022 and 2022 preview.
https://github.com/snuup/Visual-Studio-DebuggerVisualizer-Issue

This repo holds trivial type + visualizer + console applications for c# and f# .
The reason for the 2 console apps is weird, while the visualizer does not open with the quite unhelpful error message "Could not load this custom viewer" for both console apps in VS 2022, it succeeds when the type is instantiated in the c# console app, but still fails in the f# console app in VS 2022 Preview. So the good thing is that 2022 is preview is constantly better, so there is progress. Yet I need Visualizers working from F#, so that should work too. In addition, using ildasm to examine the assemblies I find it bizarre that the visualizer works for a c# console app but not for an f# console app, considering that the instantiated type comes from the same library assembly in both cases.
I tried all the tips here on SO like deleting all temporary caches and folders. I also opened an issue.
In brief, this fails:
f# console app with type definition
type FX() =
    member _.Name = "hase"

let f x =
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();  // opening visualizer fails  

f (FX())

visualizer in c#
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(
    typeof(EasterBunnyVisualizer),
    TargetTypeName = "Program+FX, FSharpConsole",
    Description = "easter bunny visualizer")
]

public class EasterBunnyVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
{
    public EasterBunnyVisualizer () : base(FormatterPolicy.Json) {}
    protected override void Show (IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider p)
    {
        // does not matter
    }
}

The visualizer shows up in the variable window, so is correctly configured, but does not open from an f# app in 2022 preview. In VS 2022 it fails in both cases anyway. at least !OMMIW ;)

I've taken the initiative to replicate your issue using Visual Studio 2022 on my system, strictly adhering to the code you've provided. Interestingly, everything functions seamlessly on my end. This suggests that the problem may be specific to your Visual Studio configuration, potentially linked to the dependencies you've mentioned or another underlying cause.
To gain a clearer understanding of the issue, I recommend gathering the Visual Studio logs.For .NET projects, you can click in the build output window and press Ctrl+S. Visual Studio prompts you for a location to save the information from the Output window into a log file.
I sincerely hope that you're able to swiftly resolve the issue at hand.

That was very very helpful, thank you so much for your efforts @zhenn-zhang, I keep trying.

I just tried it on a different machine with an updated VS 2022 (non-preview) and both console apps failed, as on my machine.

Installed VS 2022 preview on the other (very different) machine and also have the same problem as expressed in the question and in the repo.
